# Prove the Archimedean Property using MCT

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Is my attempt at proving this correct ?

*Proof.* For the sake of contradiction, suppose that there exists $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x\geq n\in\mathbb{N}$. Since $\mathbb{N}$ is always increasing, it follows by MCT that $\mathbb{N}$ converges to some limit $L$. That is, for any positive $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb{N} > N$, 
$$|n-L| < \epsilon$$
Since $\mathbb{N}$ is always increasing, if $L$ is less than any element $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$, it will be less than all the infintely many elements greater than $n$, but then it would not be the limit to which $\mathbb{N}$ converges. Therefore, it must be the case that $L\geq n\in \mathbb{N}$ and so $|n-L| = L-n$. Hence, we now we have the following inequality
$$L-n < \epsilon$$
Choose $\epsilon =1$
$$L < n+1$$
Since $(n+1)\in\mathbb{N}$, this is a contradiction. Thus, our assumption that  there exists $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x\geq n\in\mathbb{N}$ is false.

Comment: It seems good. You could also say that $(n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ being increasing implies it converges to its $\sup$, thus $L = \sup\mathbb N \geq n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: The meaning of $x\geq n\in \Bbb N$ is "$x\geq n$ and $n\in \Bbb N$".  This does not specify which $ n $.The correct way to write what you mean is $\forall n\in \Bbb N\;(x\geq n)$  or to write "$x\geq n$ for all $n\in \Bbb N.$"

Comment: Yeah that's what I intended to write, thanks! I'll make sure to use proper notation next time.